# notepad loop created automatically with VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I've created a VBScript to open notepad and write Hello. But it is opening notepad again and again

my code is:

```
WScript.Sleep 1000
Set WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "notepad"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.AppActivate "Notepad"
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "Hello"
WScript.Sleep 500
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you name your script notepad.vbs? please change the name, or

```
WshShell.Run "notepad.exe"
```

If no full path specified, windows will try to find the program in the working directory first instead of %PATH%.